# Url doesn't work after adding new page

Tags: url, html

Today i added a new page on my magento webshop.. nothing special.
But after i added that page, everytime i go on another page it adds .html in the Url and it just gives me a empty html page.
I didn't change anything in the code so I have no idea what might cause this problem.
Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: please do reindex from `system->index managment`

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala Already tried that but it didn't work..

Comment: In root of magento, you can see index.php file, you can uncomment these lines in that file : #ini_set(‘display_errors’, 1); ,

Comment: @murtuzaZabuawala have you check url-key of the page you have added ?

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala Thnks!! that helped me a lot, problem is fixed now :)

Comment: @jarischolten I have posted as answer , accept my answer, so other user take benifit if they have same problem

Comment: @jarischolten better post the actual solution as an answer (you can answer your own question and accept that answer). As it stands, this will not help much if somebody has the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In root of magento, you can see index.php file, you can uncomment these lines in that file : `#ini_set(‘display_errors’, 1);` ,

Then you can see the real errors that causing the problem

Answer (score 2):

Please check url key of the page you have added.

Remove .html from over there and your problem get solved